# Intellij runing selected code in django console instead of in python console

Tags: python, intellij-idea

In intellij, when I press Alt + Shift + E, the keybind is set to run the selected code in python console. However, when I press the shortcut, it instead runs in django console. I have restarted intellij to try to fix this but it didnt work. I also make sure that the keybind is not set to anything else, and it indeed is only set to run with python console. Previously it worked perfectly, and it would run the selected code in python console. Can't find anything on the internet about anyone else having this issue and fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by going into Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules, and under my project, there was a "django" module, just right click it and delete it and it fixed it for me.